# How to chose optimal number of lags and inputs?

Tags: time-series, genetic-algorithms

I'm using Genetic Algorithms to do inputs selection in a time series problem. The issue is that the number of possible inputs is very large (100 possible inputs + inputs' lags) and I don't know a procedure to determine the minimum number of lags to consider.

My procedure was to run a correlation analysis ex ante and leave de top 70 inputs in terms of correlation with the desired output. The problem with this procedure is that, as I increase the number of possible lags in consideration, more "ridiculous" inputs (i.e lag 140) are selected...

Comment: Can you explain how you would normally use AIC to determine the number of lags? This question isn't specific enough for me to know how to answer.

Comment: Can you show us your autocorrelation function?

Answer (score 1):

Be wary of procedures that can be referred to as "Regression Without Ethics" or procedures that believe the data rather than challenging it for consistenct/regularity . Outliers/level Shifts.SEasonal Pulses/Pulses should not be treated as regular observations but need to be isolated.  Transfer Function Identification will suggest the appropriate lag structure.